# Hitting quick fix keyboard shortcut produces 'e' in Visual Studio Code on KUbuntu 22.04

Tags: ubuntu, visual-studio-code

In my KUbuntu 22.04, when I hit the keyboard shortcut for the quick fix(which is `ctrl + .` in the application), it produces a small 'e' rather than doing whatever it was expected to do.

I did web searches on this issue and found only this [link](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/135084). However, it does not give any direction on troubleshooting this problem.

Has anyone encountered this issue? If yes, could anyone find a solution to it? If yes, please let me know in the comments or through answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is your input method's emoji picker.

If you type `Ctrl+.`, it allows you to type the name of an emoji, which will then be replaced with that emoji. It is possible to set this to some other shortcut (eg `Super+.`) instead of `Ctrl+.`.

You should search your settings to look for IBus Emoji Panel, and change the hotkey for it. I don't remember exactly where it is in KDE, but in Gnome it is under `/desktop/ibus/panel/emoji/` in the dconf Editor.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I had to change the emoji annotation shortcut in Ibus preferences.